# Remove required attribute from rails form when submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a rails form that have radio buttons with required attribute. I need that required attribute for the "Check" button. But when somebody click "Mark as absent" button, it will remove this required attribute from all those radio buttons. Here is what the form looks like:

[image]

**This is My form looks like. Its mixed with rails code, so it wont be confusing you.**

```
<table class="listing table table-striped" style="margin-bottom:50px;">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="header">
                        <th><span style="color:#F5F5F5;"><%= checkins_counter %>.</span> <%= company.name %></th>
                        <th colspan="2">

                            <div style="float:right;">

                            <% if checkin.checked == true %>
                                <%= link_to "#",:class => "minus_toggle btn btn-link", :style => "display:none;" ,:id => "minus_#{company.id}" do %>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" style="color:#fff"></span> &nbsp;
                                <% end %>   

                                <%= link_to "#",:class => "plus_toggle btn btn-link", :id => "plus_#{company.id}" do %>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" style="color:#fff"></span> &nbsp;
                                <% end %>   
                            <% else %>
                                <%= link_to "#",:class => "minus_toggle btn btn-link" ,:id => "minus_#{company.id}" do %>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" style="color:#fff"></span> &nbsp;
                                <% end %>   

                                <%= link_to "#",:class => "plus_toggle btn btn-link", :style => "display:none;" ,:id => "plus_#{company.id}" do %>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" style="color:#fff"></span> &nbsp;
                                <% end %>   
                            <% end %>

                            <%= hidden_field_tag :week, @week %>
                            <%= hidden_field_tag :company_id, company.id %>
                            <%= hidden_field_tag :checkins_size, @checkins.size %>
                            <%= hidden_field_tag :previous_target_content, previous_target %>
                            <%= f.submit "Check", :class => "btn btn-success btn-sm" %> &nbsp;
                                    <% if checkin.absent == true  %>
                                        <span id="undo_btn_<%= company.id %>">
                                            <%= f.submit "Undo", :class => "btn btn-danger btn-sm" %>
                                            Marked as absent
                                        </span>

                                        <%= f.submit "Mark as absent", :class => "btn btn-danger btn-sm absent_btn", :id => "hihi", :style => "display:none;" %>    
                                    <% else %>
                                        <span id="absent_btn_<%= company.id %>" style="display:none;">
                                            <%= f.submit "Undo", :class => "btn btn-danger btn-sm" %>
                                            Marked as absent
                                        </span>

                                        <%= f.submit "Mark as absent", :class => "btn btn-danger btn-sm absent_btn", :id => "absent_btn_#{company.id}" %>   
                                    <% end %>
                            </div>
                        </th>
                    </tr>   
                </thead>
                <% if checkin.checked == true %>
                    <tbody id="tbody_<%= company.id %>" style="display:none;">
                <% else %>
                    <tbody id="tbody_<%= company.id %>">
                <% end %>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Target</td>
                        <td>
                            <b>Previous target: </b><br/>
                            <% if previous_target != "" && !previous_target.blank? %>   
                                <i><%= previous_target %></i>
                            <% else %>
                                N/A
                            <% end %>

                            <br/>
                            <% if @week != "1" %>
                                <% if checkin.previous_target == false && checkin.checked == false  %>
                                 Done  <%= f.radio_button :previous_target, 'true', :checked => 'false', :required => true %>
                                 Not Done  <%= f.radio_button :previous_target, 'false', :checked => 'false', :required => true %>
                                <% else %>
                                 Done  <%= f.radio_button :previous_target, 'true', :required => true %>
                                 Not Done  <%= f.radio_button :previous_target, 'false', :required => true %>
                                <% end %>
                                <br/>
                            <% end %>
                            <br/>

                            <b>New target: </b><br/>
                            <%= f.text_area :target, :class => "form-control", :id => "target_#{company.id}" %>
                            <br/>
                        </td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Comment</td>
                        <td><%= f.text_area :comment, :class => "form-control" %></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Points</td>
                        <td>
                            1 <%= f.radio_button :point1, '1', :required => true %> &nbsp;
                            2 <%= f.radio_button :point1, '2', :required => true %> &nbsp;
                            3 <%= f.radio_button :point1, '3', :required => true %> &nbsp;
                            4 <%= f.radio_button :point1, '4', :required => true %> &nbsp;
                            5 <%= f.radio_button :point1, '5', :required => true %> &nbsp;
                            Execution<br/><br/>

                            1 <%= f.radio_button :point2, '1', :required => true %> &nbsp;
                            2 <%= f.radio_button :point2, '2', :required => true %> &nbsp;
                            3 <%= f.radio_button :point2, '3', :required => true %> &nbsp;
                            4 <%= f.radio_button :point2, '4', :required => true %> &nbsp;
                            5 <%= f.radio_button :point2, '5', :required => true %> &nbsp;
                            Team<br/><br/>

                            1 <%= f.radio_button :point3, '1', :required => true %> &nbsp;
                            2 <%= f.radio_button :point3, '2', :required => true %> &nbsp;
                            3 <%= f.radio_button :point3, '3', :required => true %> &nbsp;
                            4 <%= f.radio_button :point3, '4', :required => true %> &nbsp;
                            5 <%= f.radio_button :point3, '5', :required => true %> &nbsp;
                            Initiative<br/><br/>

                            1 <%= f.radio_button :point4, '1', :required => true %> &nbsp;
                            2 <%= f.radio_button :point4, '2', :required => true %> &nbsp;
                            3 <%= f.radio_button :point4, '3', :required => true %> &nbsp;
                            4 <%= f.radio_button :point4, '4', :required => true %> &nbsp;
                            5 <%= f.radio_button :point4, '5', :required => true %> &nbsp;
                            Prompt communication <br/><br/>

                            1 <%= f.radio_button :point5, '1', :required => true %> &nbsp;
                            2 <%= f.radio_button :point5, '2', :required => true %> &nbsp;
                            3 <%= f.radio_button :point5, '3', :required => true %> &nbsp;
                            4 <%= f.radio_button :point5, '4', :required => true %> &nbsp;
                            5 <%= f.radio_button :point5, '5', :required => true %> &nbsp;
                            Coachability<br/>
                        </td>
                        <td></td>   
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

**And here is my javascript that I have tried to do:**

```
$(".absent_btn").click(function()
{
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().find('tbody :input').each(function(){
        $(this).removeAttr('required');​​​​​
    });
});
```

**p/s:** *I need to level up because I have multiple forms on the page like you can see on the picture above*.

Answer (score 1):

code is work:

```
$(".absent_btn").click(function()
{
    $(this).parents("table").find("input[type=radio]").each(function(){
        $(this).removeAttr('required');​​​​​
    });
});
```

Comment: The selector is .parent(), not parents()

Comment: Hm looks promising, but somehow this is not working..The form keeps popping up "Please select one of this options"

Comment: First of all, jQuery have parents() method,unless you do not use jQuery.
Than, if is not working, you can see error on F12 and find out what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to level up. Just apply the selector on the `tbody`.

```
$(".absent_btn").click(function()
{
    $(this).closest('form').find('tbody input').each(function(){
        $(this).removeAttr('required');​​​​​
    });
});
```

For toggling:

```
$(".absent_btn").click(function()
{
    if($(this).is(":checked"))
    {
      $(this).closest('form').find('tbody input').each(function(){
          $(this).removeAttr('required');
      });
    }
    else
    {
      $(this).closest('form').find('tbody input').each(function(){
          $(this).attr('required','required');
      });
    }
});
```

Comment: Hm i need to level up because I actually have multiple forms on the page with the same inputs name and all. Please see the updated photo in my question. How could i use your solution for this? Thanks!

Comment: For multiple forms, just use parent('form') as primary selector. I've updated the code in the solution

Comment: Hm I have tried your solution, but the form keeps popping up "Please select one of this options". Is it because im using rails form or something?

Comment: It doesn't make any difference which language you are using as long as they end up being html after parsing. is the element popping up "Please select one of this options" in the same form or some other ?

Comment: It's in the same form

Comment: Hey, can u try look at this simpler version: https://jsfiddle.net/ryzalyusoff/2ass96kf/ ? Even in this simpler version, the solution doesn't works..The radio button still has the "required" attribute after clicking the button

Comment: You need to use closest selector instead of parent. Updated solution and fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/2ass96kf/2/

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why .removeAttr is not working for me. I have tried to inspect it and the browser gave me "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL" error which is not useful at all.

Anyway, this is the solution that finally works for me:

```
$(".absent_btn").click(function()
{
    $(this).parents('table').find('tbody input').prop('required', false);
});
```